# APC installation error on MediaTemple DV Server

Tags: linux, apc, pecl, mediatemple

Hi I am trying to install APC via pecl in mediatemple DV server, but i am getting this error. Can someone help?

```
[root@klph-jyj2 ~]# mkdir -p /root/chroot /root/tmp
[root@klph-jyj2 ~]# mount --bind / /root/chroot
[root@klph-jyj2 ~]# mount --bind /root/tmp /root/chroot/tmp
[root@klph-jyj2 ~]# chroot /root/chroot
[root@klph-jyj2 /]# pecl install apc
downloading APC-3.1.13.tgz ...
Starting to download APC-3.1.13.tgz (Unknown size)
....done: 3,582 bytes
Could not get contents of package "/tmp/pear/download/APC-3.1.13.tgz". Invalid tgz file.
Download of "pecl/apc" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/APC"
Download failed
install failed
```

install failed

Answer (score 0):

[Googling for the error message](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22but%20it%20is%20not%20a%20valid%20package%20archive%22), I find several results that indicate a bug in Ubuntu.

Apparently there are some workarounds, the easiest being the installation of an uncompressed version:

```
pecl install -Z apc
```

Comment: By the way, you should try installing APC from the distribution, there should be a package `php-apc`. Unless you're using PHP 5.5+, then switch to APCU + opcache.

Comment: Did you try installing the uncompressed archive?